# Using a HashMap to store properties of all primitive types

Tags: java

I am looking to use a HashMap to store properties in a Block class to make the whole property process more efficient and flexible. What I have so far is basically a BlockProperty class that stores the data "internally" as a string and is parsed using the correct parser (double, float, int, boolean, etc.) by checking the value of the "property type" against a static class with a final array as a list.

I would like to be able to request the value in the class of a certain property and it would return the value in its proper primitive type.

The Property Type List - Can be rearranged in any order with get methods for finding index and returning index values.

```
protected static final String[] type = {"int","float","long","short","boolean","String","double","Object"};
```

Block Property If-statements.

```
public Object getAsPrimitiveData()
{
    if(!isObjectType)
    {
        if(propertyType == BlockPropertyTypes.getIndexWithType("String"))
            return internalPropertyData;
        else if(propertyType == BlockPropertyTypes.getIndexWithType("int"))
            return processIntType();
        else if(propertyType == BlockPropertyTypes.getIndexWithType("short"))
            return processShortType();
        else if(propertyType == BlockPropertyTypes.getIndexWithType("long"))
            return processLongType();
        else if(propertyType == BlockPropertyTypes.getIndexWithType("boolean"))
            return processBooleanType();
        else if(propertyType == BlockPropertyTypes.getIndexWithType("float"))
            return processFloatType();
        else
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Property type is invalid.");
    }
```

The process****Type(s) all call a method similar to the one below but are modified for their respective types. (With extra output for debugging purposes)

```
public float processFloatType()
{
    try
    {
        return Float.parseFloat(internalPropertyData);
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        Notifier.printException(e);
        Notifier.cwarn("Property Type and Property Data do not match types! " + this.propertyType + " == " + BlockPropertyTypes.getIndexWithType("float") + "?? returning -1;");
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Post code: we're not mind readers here.

Comment: My apologies. Let me know if you need more

Comment: What we need now is an actual question.

Comment: @EJP Basically, a way to return the proper primitive types for each property  when they are called for whatever it might be without having to explicitly say so in the code. (Such as calling the processFloat method in code when you know that a certain property is a float value).

Comment: @ScaryWombat Whoops! I had that commented out for testing and never finished it. I will edit.

Comment: Consider using an enum and a switch instead of repeated calls to getIndexWithType.

Comment: Also, why are you trying to return integer -1 from processFloat instead of just propagating the exception? You will end up returning -1.0f, which I presume is a valid number in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Number

```
    int a = 5;
    float f = 5.5f;
    double d = 5.5;
    
    Number na = a;
    Number nf = f;
    Number nd = d;
    
    System.out.println(na.getClass());
    System.out.println(nf.getClass());
    System.out.println(nd.getClass());
```

**output**

> class java.lang.Integer
>
> class java.lang.Float
>
> class java.lang.Double